# How to use boringssl with Android NDK

Tags: android, openssl, android-ndk

We are developing a printing service using IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) on Android.
I used the `CUPS` library that supports the IPP protocol.

Now you can connect to the printer using the `ipp://` scheme and print. However, `426` is requested for some printers. This error indicates that TLS (SSL) is required.

If you look at the `CUPS` library, there are three SSL authentication codes.

- tls-darwin.c
- tls-gnutls.c
- tls-boringssl.c

Here I am going to use `boringssl`.

I found the code at [google/boringssl](https://github.com/google/boringssl)

I would like to use the library like `#include<openssl/ssl.h>` rather than using the above code by adding it to my project.

Now I am getting the error below.

```
../../../../src/main/cups/tls-boringssl.c:30:10: fatal error: 'openssl/err.h' file not found
  #include <openssl/err.h>
```

Please tell me how. Thank you.